# Is there a way to add keywords to the start menu shortcut a ClickOnce deploy creates?

Tags: clickonce, deployment

We deploy a Winforms app with a name like "Its Our App".
People refer to it as IOA.  I'd like to keep the full name for the shortcut but have watched many users hit the Windows key on their keyboard, type IOA, and state in wonder, "Where's It's Our App"?.

Is there a way to add IOA as a keyword for the shortcut, without adding it to the name, so Windows Search (or other desktop search apps) recognize it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply keywords to shortcuts in the start menu.

As I see it you have three choices (with #3 being the best option):

1) Change the folder name of your application to "[Company] It's Our App" instead of simply "[Company]" and change the name of your application to "IOA".

2) Extend the Windows Search service:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965362(VS.85).aspx

3) Change the name of your product to "It's Our App (IOA)". Having "IOA" in there should enable the start menu search to pick it up.

Comment: Looks like #3 it is.  I was hoping that wasn't the only good answer.  Thanks Adam.

Comment: The notion of being able to add keywords to start menu shortcuts seems like a bad idea so I'm not surprised it's not implemented. Any a-hole junkware could use "Word" as one of its shortcuts so any time you wanted to write a document that app would show up.